# How to call a function by an array of argument values?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function with 2 parameters:

```
function foo(a,b)
{
    return a + b
}
```

then I can call the function with arguments:

```
c = foo(10,20)
```

Now if I assemble the argument values in an array,

```
var args = []
args.push(100)
args.push(200)
```

How can I call the function by passing in the array?

```
d = foo(args.WHAT_IS_THIS_FUNCTION())
```

for example,

```
d = foo(args.join())
```

is equivalent to

```
d = foo("100,200")
```

which is not what I wanted.

The question is simple: how can I call function "foo" by feeding an array as argument(s)?

Comment: `foo.apply(thisPointer, args);`

Comment: For reference head over to Mozilla docs and view Function.prototype.apply(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: if the function does not use `this.`, any value would do `foo.apply(0, [1,2])`